# how does default_proc work

Tags: ruby

The following code was taken from a RubyTapas screencast, but it wasn't explained sufficiently for a person of my experience.  Setting up a hash like this

```
config = Hash.new do |h,k|
  h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)
end
```

allows one to set and access values in the following way

```
config[:production][:database][:adapter] = 'mysql'
puts config[:production][:database][:adapter] # => "mysql"
```

When I do

```
puts config.inspect
```

It reveals a nested hash.

```
{:production=>{:database=>{:adapter=>"mysql"}}}
```

However, if I modify the code (to just play around with it) to remove &h.default_proc

```
    config = Hash.new do |h,k|
      h[k] = Hash.new()      #&h.default_proc removed from parameter
    end
```

I get this error

```
 undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I don't get what is happening with Hash.new(&h.default_proc), when, for example, I do this

```
    config[:production][:database][:adapter] = 'mysql'
    puts config[:production][:database][:adapter] # => "mysql"
```

Can you break down that, explaining in detail how the block `&hdefault_proc` is working in this context.  Please also explain if you can when the proc is getting called. Why is the proc necessary to make this work

```
    config[:production][:database][:adapter] = 'mysql'
```

and how does the proc get called? I thought you have to do proc.call to actually call the proc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: RubyTapas #032-Hash Default Blocks - for those following along

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are taking it the wrong way. `&h` is not a meaningful unit in this context. It is `&` attached to `h.default_proc`. That is a **proc** `h.default_proc` turned into a **block**. Similar thing applies to the splat operator `*`. The associative precedence of `&` and `*` is always the last. The reason is clear: it does not make sense otherwise.

---

Suppose you have:

```
config = Hash.new() # or `{}`
```

then, whenever you access `config` with an un-existing key, it will return `nil`, so

```
config[:production][:database]
```

will return an error because the method `[]` is not defined on `config[:production]`, which equals `nil`. When you do:

```
config = Hash.new do |h,k|
  h[k] = Hash.new()
end
```

then, it will be ensured that when you access `config` with an un-existing key, it creates a new hash as a value. So

```
config[:production][:database]
```

will now be okay because the method `[]` is defined on `config[:production]`, which equals the newly created hash `{}`. But still,

```
config[:production][:database][:adapter]
```

will return an error because the method `[]` is not defined on  `config[:production][:database]`, which equals `nil`. If you instead have:

```
config = Hash.new do |h,k|
  h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)
end
```

then, that means that, when you access `config` with an un-existing key like:

```
config[:production]
```

the hash that is created this time will have a `default_proc` set to the same one as `config`, which means that

```
config[:procuction][:database]
```

is not a hash that returns `nil` to a non-existing key call, but a hash that returns another hash to a non-existing key call. So this time,

```
config[:production][:database][:adapter]
```

will not return an error. Similar thing happens with an arbitrary depth within the hash.

Comment: ok, thanks but can you please still explains what happens with the proc and how it gets called with the line,  config[:production][:database][:adapter] = 'mysql'

Comment: Thanks for the longer explanation. One thing you might add, if you don't mind, is why it's not necessary to do default_proc.call. I thought you always had to 'call' a proc. When is the default_proc being called exactly?

Comment: `default_proc` is called when you try to access a hash with a non-existing key. Without it, it will return `nil`.

Comment: but since it's turned into a block, it doesn't need to be called via the 'call' method? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: A blog post, which explains Hash#default_proc extensively: http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2015/08/dive-into-hashdefaultproc.html